# Not using unwrapping in guard statements

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, forced-unwrapping

I understand the use of optionals enough to know when its necessary to unwrap an optional using the exclamation point.  Why is it that the exclamation point isn't needed in a guard statement?

This code works and compiles but doesn't use exclamation points:

```
struct Blog{

  var author:String?
  var name: String?

}

func blogInfo2(blog:Blog?){
  guard let blog = blog else {
    print("Blog is nil")
    return
  }
  guard let author = blog.author, name = blog.name else {
    print("Author or name is nil")
    return
  }
  print("BLOG:")
  print(" Author: \(author)")
  print(" name: \(name)")
}
```

This code also works if you do put the exclamation points:

```
struct Blog{

  var author:String?
  var name: String?

}

func blogInfo2(blog:Blog?){
  guard let blog = blog! else {
    print("Blog is nil")
    return
  }
  guard let author = blog.author!, name = blog.name! else {
    print("Author or name is nil")
    return
  }
  print("BLOG:")
  print(" Author: \(author)")
  print(" name: \(name)")
}
```

Isn't this a little contradictory or can someone clearly explain why the exclamation point isn't needed?

Comment: I'm surprised that the `guard let blog = blog!` version works for you.  What version of Swift are you using?

Comment: @PhillipMills yes now I realize after trying it in an online swift compiler because I'm using Xcode 8 beta version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`guard let unwrapped = optional` is an [Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) (no link available directly to the correct book section, unfortunately). It *safely* tries to unwrap the value in the optional. If there is a value, the unwrap succeeds, and the value is assigned to the given name.

You should heavily favor the use of optional bindings, with either `guard` or `if` (the difference is the scope of the "unwrapped" name) over the use of forced unwrapping with `!`. A failed force unwrap is a *fatal error*; your program will simply crash.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand the use of optionals enough to know when its necessary to unwrap an optional using the exclamation point.

I have the feeling that you *don't* understand Swift Optionals enough if you make that assertion.

The contract behind an Optional is that it may or may not be nil; you don't know it and therefore you have to Unwrap it (like opening a box and see what's inside) before you can tell.

The box may be empty (nil Optional) or it may contain a value.

There are *very few reasons* to use the Forced Unwrap (`!`). **Very Few**, and it's generally considered a bad practice in *most* (but not all) cases.

To continue the analogy, by force unwrapping stuff, you're saying *there is something in this box, and I want you to trust me and don't check*.

Knowing that an Empty box will *crash* your application, this is a very dangerous thing to do, considering Optionals were introduced in Swift to *protect* you from these sort of crashes to begin with.

The `if let/guard let` statements basically peek inside the box and if there is something, they give it to you, but they also give you the chance to do something else in case the box is empty.

Xcode does *force unwrapping* when using IBOutlets because *by design* the contract is that those objects *will be available* by the time you can use them in your view controller, but unless you're 100% sure a value is not going to be `nil` then it's almost always better (and future proof) to use a `guard` statement (or an `if`).

In my experience, even when you *know for sure*, it's still safer to toss a `guard` and forget about the future problems that may arise.

Comment: I would say that the usage of `!` is limited to two cases. a/ when you can't really recover from that error (e.g. `nil` returned due to failed memory allocation) b/ when `nil` should be considered a programming error. For example, when creating a URL from a *literal* string. In that case that `!` works as an assert.

Comment: @Sulthan Agree that in _very few_ cases, `!` is ok, usually project dependent, but it's usually preferred to gracefully handle the error (failed memory allocation) and offer an alternative or inform the user what happened than a simple crash; a crash is the worst possible outcome, avoid it at all costs. The language/framework is giving you tools to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The exclamation "force" unwraps an optional. `guard let` or `if let` unwraps it without forcing anything, so no exclamation point is used.